# Python Multiple Inheritance child(parent1, parent2) access parent2 __init__

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

let's say I have this class

```
class child(parent1, parent2):
    pass
```

Would it be possible to access `parent2.__init__`, if parent1 also has a defined `__init__` ?.

Here is my complete code.

```
class parent1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color="Blue"

class parent2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure="Triangle"

class child(parent1,parent2):
    pass


juan=child()
try:
    print(juan.color)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
try:
    print(juan.figure)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print(juan.__dict__)
```

I've tried with

```
class child(parent1,parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(parent2).__init__()
```

but maybe I am missing something?

Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: All three classes should use `super` if any of them do. That's what allows each function to be called in the order inferred from the inheritance tree, rather than requiring explicit references to specific methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent1` and `parent2`, if expected to be used in a cooperative multiple inheritance setting, should call `super`.

```
class parent1:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = "Blue"

class parent2:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.figure = "Triangle"
```

When you define `child`, its method resolution order determines which `__init__` gets called first, as well as determining which class `super()` refers to when each time it gets called. In your actual example,

```
class child(parent1,parent2):
    pass
```

`parent1.__init__` is called first (since `child` does not override `__init__`), and its use of `super()` refers to `parent2`. If you had instead defined

```
class child2(parent2, parent1):
    pass
```

then `parent2.__init__` would be called first, and its use of `super()` would refer to `parent1`.

`super()` is used not to ensure that `object.__init__` (which doesn't do anything) is called, but rather `object.__init__` exists so that it *can* be called once a chain of `super()` calls reaches the end. (`object.__init__` itself does *not* use `super`, as it is guaranteed to be the last class in the method resolution order of any other class.)

Comment: That's exaclty it. In this particular case, it works even if I just write super().__init__() on parent1, because when parent1 is "called", the super().__init__() refers to parent 2.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If `super().__init__` is the only thing your `__init__` does, it can be left undefined, as you are just explicitly calling what would have been implicitly called anyway.